# Extract value from a super field

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a field `event_params` that is type `super`.

Example value of event_params:

```
[
{"key":"type","value":{"string_value":"blah"}},
{"key":"value","value":{"double_value":5.99}},
{"key":"category","value":{"string_value":"add-ons"}},
{"key":"event_id","value":{"string_value":"956bb654-be90-5334-91a3-ee97074da0eb"}},
]
```

I would like to get event_id without unfolding the whole thing, I just want to drill down into it and pull up event id.

After [reading docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html) and messing around, I can d0 this:

```
select
    event_params[4].value,
    event_params[4].key,
    event_params
from "myschema"."mytable"
where event_name = 'purchase'
and event_timestamp = 1660193632449615;
```

Here I used indexing with 4. But data will not necessarily be in the same order. INstead I want to filter based on the `key` being `event_id`.

How can I modify this: `event_params[4].key` to instead filter based on the name of the key I want, in this case `event_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```sql
select
    event_name,
    ep
from 
    "myschema"."mytable" m, 
     m.event_params as ep
where 
    event_name = 'purchase'
    and event_timestamp = 1660193632449615
    and ep.key = 'event_id';
```